# How to Access Back and Start buttons in windows mobile 10 using C#?

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am trying to map existing Back, Start buttons using javascript into two buttons. I have tried below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.phone.ui.input.hardwarebuttons

```
var hardwareButtons = Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons;
function backPressed() {
hardwareButtons.addEventListener("backpressed", function (e) {
    // Navigate back in your webview. 
    e.handled = true; // Notifies OS that you've handled the back button event.
    alert("Back pressed");
});
}
```

But this has only camera and back button only. I want to access start and back buttons separately or trigger multi tasking view and show start actions. anyone has an idea?

Comment: There's a [`SystemNavigationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager) class to handle back button press.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not make this available (using public APIs). If you don't mind using unofficial APIs that will prevent your app from appearing in the Store, it might be possible - it was on previous Windows Phone versions, at least - but it cannot be done using the official APIs.

Comment: that is fine with me. could you send me the unofficial APIs you have mentioned?